# Adding variables inside constants

Tags: php, string, variables, constants

I'm using constants for my error messages inside the Views, and I want to be able to use variables inside them for easier management.

Most of my constants looks like this:

```
const SUCCESSFULLY_REGISTERED = "<p class='success'>Registration successful!.</p>";
```

What I want to do is to use a variable for the css class, so that it's easier to change them all in one place. This is what I've tried:

```
const SUCCESSFULLY_REGISTERED = "<p class='$this->cssClassSuccess'>Registration successful!.</p><p>Log in with the username and password you registered with.</p>";
```

By some reason that doesn't work and raises the error message below. Why is that and how can this be done in a way that works?

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in .../View/RegisterView.php on line 15
```

Comment: constant != variable; thus you can't add dynamic content to constants…

Comment: Well, as @Mike wrote below: "constants (as the name implies) need to be constant"

Answer (score 7):

This is not possible if you define a constant.

> **Manual:** "The value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a property, a result of a mathematical operation,
>   or a function call."

[Constant Manual php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php)
[Constant Expression](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php)

Comment: @holyredbeard: Is your questions answered? Then you should mark one answer as correct.

Answer (score 5):

This won't work because constants (as the name implies) need to be constant, but you can work around it with `printf()`.

Example:

```
const SUCCESSFULLY_REGISTERED = '<p class="%s">Registration successful blah blah blah!</p>'
```

And then in your view script:

```
printf(SUCCESSFULLY_REGISTERED, $this->cssClassSuccess);
```

The `%s` in the constant will be replaced with the value of `$this->cssClassSuccess`

Answer (score 1):

**Manual:** As of PHP 5.3.0, it's possible to reference the class using a variable.

Check the following class below:

```
<?php

class A{

    function __construct($v)
    {
        define("MyConstant",$v);
        echo "MyConstant is ". MyConstant;
    }
}

$a = new A("hello"); //will print MyConstant is hello
?>
```

In the code above we are assigning the value of a variable ($v) to constant MyConstant. It will not give an error and the result of running this function will be `MyConstant is hello`

However, suppose you added a new line like so:

```
$a = new A("hello"); //will print MyConstant is hello
$b = new A("New Value"); //will generate Constant MyConstant already defined notice..
```

Here the line `$b = new A("New Value");` will throw a notice stating: `Notice: Constant MyConstant already defined`. This is because constants defined within a class are pseudo-class-constants, similar to being static variables in terms of the context to which the scope is bound. And since constants cannot be changed, and their scope is bound to the class, calling the error line above is essentially trying to "redefine" the constant, which as you know will result in the aforementioned error.

Having said that remember that if you use `define` to create a constant inside a class it is not a pure class constant - you cannot call it as `A::MyConstant`. At the same time if you had done `const AnotherConstant = "Hey";` in `Class A` you can call it as `A::AnotherConstant`. However when using `const` to create a constant you cannot set its value to a variable.

I hope this gives a better clarity on how dynamic variables can and cannot be assigned to a constant.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that you can dynamically generate a constant is using the define function like below.  But as another answer pointed out, this won't be a class level constant.

```
define('SUCCESSFULLY_REGISTERED', "<p class='$this->cssClassSuccess'>Registration successful!.</p><p>Log in with the username and password you registered with.</p>");
```

The constant from that point forward can be referred to with SUCCESSFULL_REGISTERED and will be immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Problem: Cast custom messages and pass variables for easier management
Solution: use a Decorator pattern

```
interface HtmlElementInterface {
    public function getText();
    public function render();
}

class DivDecorator implements HtmlElementInterface {
    protected $innerHtml;
    protected $class;
    public function __construct($class = null, $innerHtml = null) {
        $this->innerHtml = $innerHtml;
        $this->class = $class;
    }

    public function getText() {
        return $this->text;
    }

    public function render() {
        return "<div class='{$this->class}'>" . $this->innerHtml . "</div>";
    }

}

$message = "Error in the app";
$div = new DivDecorator("myclass", $message);
echo $div->render();
```